# Some example schemas on swagger not displaying

Tags: django, swagger, swagger-ui, drf-yasg, drf-spectacular

New over here..

Has anyone encountered a problem that occurs in swagger where it shows some specific number of urls with their properties and example schemas. While for the rest it just gives the default value "string".

E.g If I have a total of 70 urls for the first 30 urls it gives the accurate example schemas while for others it just gives "string" as the example schema
[My swagger UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvgsa.jpg)
The "string" Example value then shows up for all urls after the api/user/verify

I have tested both drf_yasg and drf-spectacular but got the same result

Comment: without seeing your OpenAPI file, hard to diagnose it.  An educated guess says you have a syntax error and the rest of the file is not being read correctly for those nodes. Post it here and we can help you fix it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I has the same problem. Seems it has a problem in the newest version of Swagger
I fix it with adding "SWAGGER_UI_DIST": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swagger-ui-dist@5.11.5" to SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS